# Angularjs Dependent State->cities dropdown, retrieve cities from http.get service

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am looking for a way to use an http.get service to retrieve the cities from the federated state they belong. I create a dependent dropdown of cities from a choosen state.

Here is a working fiddle to serve as a base to a dinamic version:

http://jsfiddle.net/amrigo/v8u7v4af/

I meant to have states and cities:

```
function CountryController($scope) {
                $scope.countries = {
                    'Michigan': {
                        'Detroit': [],
                        'Flint': []
                    },
                    'Texas': {
                        'Austin': [],
                        'Houston': []
                    },
                    'California': {
                        'Los Angeles': [],
                        'San Francisco': []
                    }

                };
            }
```

How can i write a factory that receives the state id and adjust to the JSON format: ('Los Angeles': [],'San Francisco': []).

```
.factory('citiesByState', function($http) {
    return {
        getVersion: function(id) {
            return $http.get('http://www.service.com/ckeck_cities.php')
                            .then(function(response) {
                                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});


<select class="form-control input-lg" id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input-lg" id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What state ID? Data doesn't contain any ID properties. Likely be simpler also if you were using nested arrays data instead of nested objects

Comment: You mean this format: ? `$scope.countries = {
                'id':'1', 'stateName':'Michigan': {
                    {'id':'1', 'name':'Detroit'},
                    {'id':'2', 'name':'Flint'}
                },
                'id':'2', 'stateName':'Texas': {
                    {'id':'3', 'name':'Austin'},
                    {'id':'4', 'name':'Houston'}
                },
                'id':'3', 'stateName':'California': {
                    {'id':'5', 'name':'Los Angeles'},
                    {'id':'6', 'name':'San Francisco'}
                }
            };`

Comment: close but that's not valid structure and is all objects still, not arrays

Comment: Must be this : `'Michigan': [
                    {'id':'1', 'name':'Detroit'},
                    {'id':'2', 'name':'Flint'}
                ],
                'Texas': [
                    {'id':'3', 'name':'Austin'},
                    {'id':'4', 'name':'Houston'}
                ]`

Comment: yes, will likely find that  lot easier to work with since it can be sorted and filtered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory will fetch the cities by given state and save it in a state->cities map.

```
.factory('citiesByState', function($http) {
    return {
        locationData: {},
        getCities: function(id) {
            var that = this;
            return $http.get('http://www.service.com/ckeck_cities.php?state='+id)
                            .then(function(response) {
                                that.locationData[id] = response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You then inject the service into your controller and use that state->cities map to update your UI.

```
function CountryController($scope, $citiesByState) {
        $citiesByState.getCities(1); // pass your state id
        $scope.cities = $citiesByState.locationData; //cities will contain your data for the given state when the response is received
}
```

Comment: How can i pass the result data to the template ? and bind the variables like id and name to the select box ? can it be in this format? 
`'Michigan': [
                    {'id':'1', 'name':'Detroit'},
                    {'id':'2', 'name':'Flint'}
                ],
                'Texas': [
                    {'id':'3', 'name':'Austin'},
                    {'id':'4', 'name':'Houston'}
                ]`
 `<select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">`

Comment: Yes, pretty close. Not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/815kd22e/. Shows how you can pick states and select corresponding list of cities.

Comment: I figure out how to get the id for the city : `alert('You selected ' + city.id+' '+city.name);` I need to get id for state too wich changes i need to make into the json structure ?

Comment: If you modify your json a little bit, you can do it easily. Instead of representing it as an object, make it into an array and use it like in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/815kd22e/3/. I have also modified the service to help you with your JSON data.

Comment: The fiddle helps me a lot, thank´s. Maybe i can not see how to bind the model into a select. I add id to a state into the Json. looking now how display the state name and them populate cities

Comment: I do create [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/amrigo/815kd22e/4/) with a closer idea i am looking for to pass state id and city id i would need to use onChange and call the factory right?

Comment: Looks good. You can either do ng-change, or just use a `$scope.$watch` on the controller like this: http://jsfiddle.net/815kd22e/5/

Comment: Could not get the point about how to pass the cities to the second select box, How the cities array will populate the $scope.cities? when using ng-change how to pass state.id to the cityesByState function?

Comment: Actually the factory receives the literal "state" string as id and not a number `$citiesByState.getCities(state.id);` even that in the template i can see the correct numeric value of state.id how can i pass the state id ?